# Integrate over matrix elements

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix

I wish to perform the integral
    $$
\int \prod_{i,j}dM_{ij}\exp\left(-Tr(M^2)\right)
$$
where we integrate over the matrix elements of $M$. I tried

```
Integrate[Exp[-Tr[matrix^2]],Product[Part[matrix,i,j],{matrix}]];
```

I know this is wrong and I get "The expression i cannot be used as a part specification.", but how should I write this instead?

Comment: Do you mean the component-wise square of the matrix or the matrix product of `M` with itself?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The matrix product. But what I try to understand is not the integrand, but how to express the $dM_{ij}$ with Mathematica

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming $\prod_{i,j} dM_{i,j} = dM_{1,1} dM_{1,2}\ldots$ so as to successively integrate over each element in your matrix.

Then

```
mat = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
Integrate[Exp[-Tr[MatrixPower[mat, 2]]], ##] & @@ Flatten@mat
```

> -(1/8) π Erf[a] Erf[d] ExpIntegralEi[-2 b c]

Comment: My matrix is a GUE (`mat=RandomVariate[GaussianUnitaryMatrixDistribution[some rank]];`) and it returns me the error 'Invalid integration variable or limit(s)'

Comment: You could try starting with a symbolic matrix, then integrate, then replace the symbols with the appropriate numbers in the final output or implement integration bounds as in @Henrik's answer.  Otherwise, since your matrix is made of numeric quantities, integrating with respect to a number doesn't really work.

Answer (score 2):

Just some shot into the dark because I am not sure whether I understood  exactly want you want to compute:

```
n = 3;
M = Array[m, {n, n}];
With[{vars = Sequence @@ Transpose[{Flatten[M], ConstantArray[-∞, n^2], ConstantArray[∞, n^2]}]},
 Integrate[Exp[-Tr[M\[Transpose].M]], vars]
 ]
```

> π^(9/2)

Also notice that

```
With[{vars = Sequence @@ Transpose[{Flatten[M], ConstantArray[-∞, n^2], ConstantArray[∞, n^2]}]},
 Integrate[Exp[-Tr[M.M]], vars]
 ]
```

will lead to an error message stating that integral won't converge.

Comment: For arbitrary n, a wild guess would be (Pi)^(n^2/2) :-)